# Informed manager about leaving, he replied with ".. have lots of expectations". What does he mean by that?

Tags: professionalism, job-change, resignation, manager

I accepted an offer from a company and decided to inform my Manager. Out of respect, I felt it wouldn't be a great idea to directly resign without having a word with him first.

So I sent in the email explaining my reasons for the job switch. He replied back with:

> This is a bit surprising. I'll talk to you soon. Have lots of expectations.

Now the last part of that email is what's confusing me. From what I know, it could mean the following:

1. I expect a lot of effort from your side in order to have a smooth transition (like Knowledge Transfer sessions, finding a replacement etc)
2. Perhaps it was a typo and he meant "(I) **had** lots of expectations (from you), so it's disappointing to see you on the verge of resigning"
3. Again a typo but this time, he probably meant "(You) have a lot of **explanation** to do" [even though I mentioned the reason for leaving so this might not be a probable option]

If it matters, this is a big US MNC who has offshore development offices in India.

#### UPDATE

A bit of background about my work history at this company. I'm a relatively new hire (about 6 months). There was no probationary period as I was already an experienced candidate. From my interactions with my Manager (though very little), it appeared that he was happy with my performance. I had also got raving reviews from the client in only my second project in the company, which was duly forwarded to the whole of India team by him.

I had also worked from home many times during this time and he didn't seem to have any problems with that as I always delivered on time and without much issues. So all in all, I can say that I was a performing employee.

Comment: Honestly, could be any of the three you mentioned.  There's not a lot of context to work with, so I don't think anyone other than your boss can clarify that statement any further.  If I were you I'd try to prepare for all three as best you can.

Comment: He said "talk to you soon" so that's what you should consider. That means he wants to talk to you, probably in person rather than e-mail back and forth about this.

Comment: That's why you don't resign by e-mail but in face to face meeting. E-mail ping pong is not a way to have a constructive conversation.

Comment: It's an irrelevant typo, just press on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't speak for your manager, only way to find out what he meant is to have a discussion with him.

Most likely, having expectations (on a positive note) indicates he is willing to "negotiate" with you about the retention. That's the best guess, but, a guess nonetheless.

There is nothing to be worried, have the discussion and you'll find out yourself.

Comment: I did add some background if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't react to it! Just continue your move.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that seems like a bad move. I don't want to burn any bridges as I might rely on him as a reference in future interviews. It's always best to leave a door open in case something doesn't work out in future.

Comment: @asprin trying to explain an unclear reply gives you headache for nothing. Everything will be clear in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

As merely a possibility, since we're not psychic :) ...

I think it's an expression of disappointment that you're leaving so soon and they had planned your work and contribution well into the future.

The use of 'have' over 'had' might be a prelude to a counter-offer.